# Best client for syncing to OwnCloud

Tags: owncloud

I've installed **OwnCloud Server** and got everything to work. But is there a good client for it?

I'm looking for a good client for windows that even can delete files in the cloud if I delete something in the local directory.

Answer (score 3):

The [official ownCloud client](http://owncloud.org/install/#desktop) is available for Windows, Mac and GNU/Linux and it works perfectly. And it does what you ask for.

Comment: Official ownCloud client is really pretty good. But there is some pecularities when it is installed on Windows XP. I've also checked Windows 7, Android and Mac - and everything works flawlessly.

Comment: It's good enough until it losts some of your work. Can't recommend use of it, because of dangerous two-way sync.

Answer (score 2):

If you want owncloud client then you can download these from official owncloud site https://owncloud.org/install/ ,here you can find clients for every platform like  for windows ,linux android..etc